# "Магический" плей-лист PHP

Tags: flashvideo, php, flash-player

Вот [ссылка](http://video-dom2.ru/onlinetv/), на странице есть плеер. Как достать плейлист?

P.S. У кого загрузится плейлист, указанный в коде [этой](http://video-dom2.ru/onlinetv/pl_dom2.php) страницы - обновите страницу, готов поспорить, второй раз Вы его не увидите, но сам плеер как-то всё равно достаёт плейлист, собственно вопрос - как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот выдрал плейлист с кодировкой сам разберешься. [Ссылка](http://webfile.ru/5894769)

Comment: Дело в том, что плей-лист там обновляется каждый день, и мне его нужно парсить, и задача именно в том, как бы его получать когда мне вздумается, а не на удачу...

Comment: firefox плагин FireBug

Comment: Чуууть чуть поподробнее можно, пожаалуйста? (:

Comment: качаешь плагин FireBug, перезапускаешь FireFox. нажимаешь на жука справа сверху.. тыкаешь вкладку Сеть, потом Все, затем не очищать..  заходишь на страницу http://video-dom2.ru/onlinetv/ там смотришь необходимый тебе файл.. нажми плюсик чтобы развернуть инфу о файле

Comment: Мы говорили о [файле плейлиста ][1], а там FireBug не поможет, т.к. после обновления страницы - ноль движений


  [1]: http://video-dom2.ru/onlinetv/pl_dom2.php

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!!!!!!!
Последний вопросик, и закроем уже эту ветку...
Как бы к этому файлу через РНР подобраться? Просто так через file_get_contents() он не открывает...

Answer (score 2):

Именно то, что Вам нужно. Код полностью рабочий и выводит искомый плэйлист.

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$headers="Host: video-dom2.ru\r\nAccept: */*\r\nAccept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4\r\nAccept-Charset: windows-1251,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/11.10 Chromium/17.0.963.79 Chrome/17.0.963.79 Safari/535.11\r\n";
$sock=fsockopen('video-dom2.ru', 80);
$query="GET /onlinetv/ HTTP/1.0\r\n".$headers."\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $query);
$res=fread($sock, 2048);
fclose($sock);
preg_match_all('/set-cookie: (.+?)[;\n\r]/i', $res, $arr);
$sock=fsockopen('video-dom2.ru', 80);
$query="GET /onlinetv/pl_dom2.php HTTP/1.0\r\n".$headers."Referer: http://video-dom2/onlinetv/player/player.swf\r\nCookie: ";
foreach ($arr[1] as $k=>$v){
    $query.= $v.'; ';
};
$query=substr($query, 0, strlen($query)-2);
$query.="\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $query);
$res='';
while (!feof($sock)){
    $res.=fread($sock, 512);
};
$sp=explode("\r\n\r\n", $res);
echo htmlspecialchars(gunzip($sp[1]))."\r\n";

function gunzip($zipped) {
      $offset = 0;
      if (substr($zipped,0,2) == "\x1f\x8b")
         $offset = 2;
      if (substr($zipped,$offset,1) == "\x08")  {
         return gzinflate(substr($zipped, $offset + 8));
      }
      return "Unknown Format";
}  
?>
```

Comment: Мощный ответ, обязательно попробую.
Спасибо!!!

Comment: Блин((( Забыл совсем про куки. Если выключить куки, то плеер не грузит плэйлист. А мой вариант не передает куки, поэтому такая короткая длина 20 байт: там наверно нечто вроде "Включите куки".

Comment: Поправил ответ.

Comment: Странно, у меня просто пустая страница, т.е. вообще ничего.

Comment: Странно. Я просто скопировал код из своего ответа в новый файл php и увидел плейлист.  
Наверно Вам стоит попробовать также. Если Вы вставите этот код в середину другого кода, то произойдет ошибка из-за header.

Comment: Это понятно, но код ничего не выводит, даже ошибок :))

Comment: Вы что-то не так делаете. Проверьте на другом хосте. Скрипт полностью рабочий. Либо Ваш хостинг не поддерживает http протокол в php, либо нет библиотек для работы с gzip, либо этот сайт уже заблокировал Ваш IP и ничего не отдает.

Answer (score 0):

Несколько раз проверил - подгружается, но уже с задержкой в секунду.
А вот по ссылке http://video-dom2.ru/onlinetv/pl_dom2.php - нет ничего, то есть абсолютно ничего, даже если исходный код посмотреть.
Кстати, плееру не важно - отображается плейлист или нет, для него собственно путь к плейлисту прописан ))

Comment: Как раз таки плееру плей-лист важен, иначе ему при каждой подгрузке неоткуда брать данные, а он берёт откуда-то... В этом то и проблема.

Comment: Наверно уже поздно и вы устали ))) Читайте внимательно, я написал, что плееру важен путь плейлисту, к файлу в котором плейлист, а отображается он или нет - плееру пофиг.

Comment: Может быть (:
Да, файл плей-листа на месте, может плееру и пофиг, но он не содержит никаких данных, каким образом он выводит список серий? Файл некоторое время выводит весь плей-лист, а некоторое время - нет... Вот и вопрос, откуда плеер подгружает список серий, если данных в плей-листе нету?

Comment: Динамически он туда подгружается. А с чем связан баг "то есть - то нет" - этого я не скажу.